# How to retrieve a generated ID when saving objects with Spring Data R2DBC using Postgresql

Tags: spring, reactive, r2dbc

Could you please help me to solve the problem below

I have a entity class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

and I save it in Postgresql with the code:

```
public Mono<User> save(User user){
        return databaseClient().inTransaction(db -> {
            return db
                .insert()
                .into(User.class)
                .using(user)
                //todo: return saved user
        });
}
```

I wish to get saved User, how I can do

Answer (score 5):

Spring Data R2DBC expects your database to return generated keys. When using Postgres, then make sure to declare a column that generates Id's itself such as `SERIAL`.

In your case that would be:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id          serial CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY,
    name        varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);
```

Depending on which API you're using, you can retrieve the Id with various approaches:

- `DatabaseClient`: An `INSERT` operation returns generated values as `Map<String, Object>` by mapping column names to values. You need to extract the Id yourself.
- Using `R2dbcRepository`: Saving a new object returns a `Mono<T>` that emits the saved (updated) object which contains a generated Id.

In general, we recommend immutable objects to avoid visibility and shared mutable state issues. Spring Data leverages Lombok's `@Wither` pattern to create a new object instance when Spring Data needs to propagate data back to an object.

See also:

- Spring Data R2DBC: [`PostgresR2dbcRepositoryIntegrationTests`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/r2dbc/repository/PostgresR2dbcRepositoryIntegrationTests.java#L46)